# jQuery noConflict: none of the libraries work now instead of both

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with conflicting jQuery versions.

I thought that using `jQuery.noConflict()` would solve my problem, but it doesn't.

[This is the article that I used as a reference](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUsing_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries%26redirect%3Dno)

When I delete either of the two jQuery libraries entirely, the other one always works fine.

As you see in my code below, I import external php files to avoid code repetition on every page. My plan is also to export the Javascript code (it's too much to place in the header).
The two functionalities that I want to run in one page are:

- [Accordion](http://designmodo.com/css3-accordion-menu/)
- [Stack dock](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-os-x-style-dock-and-stack-navigation/)

My (not working) code:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="/malark/general/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/malark/general/accordion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/malark/general/jqdock/stackdock.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery.noConflict();

            $(document).ready(function () {
                    // Stack initialize
                    var openspeed = 300;
                    var closespeed = 300;
                    $('.stack2>img').toggle(function(){
                            var vertical = 0;
                            var horizontal = 0;
                            var $el=$(this);
                            $el.next().children().each(function(){
                                    $(this).animate({top: vertical + 'px', left: horizontal + 'px'}, openspeed);
                                    vertical = vertical + 55;
                                    horizontal = (horizontal+.75)*2;
                            });
                            $el.next().animate({top: '40px', left: '10px'}, openspeed).addClass('openStack')
                               .find('li a>img').animate({width: '50px', marginLeft: '9px'}, openspeed);
                            $el.animate({paddingBottom: '0'});
                    }, function(){
                            //reverse above
                            var $el=$(this);
                            $el.next().removeClass('openStack').children('li').animate({top: '-33px', left: '-10px'}, closespeed);
                            $el.next().find('li a>img').animate({width: '79px', marginLeft: '0'}, closespeed);
                            $el.animate({paddingBottom: '35px'});
                    });

                    // Stacks additional animation
                    $('.stack2 li a').hover(function(){
                            $("img",this).animate({width: '56px'}, 100);
                            $("span",this).animate({marginRight: '30px'});
                    },function(){
                            $("img",this).animate({width: '50px'}, 100);
                            $("span",this).animate({marginRight: '0'});
                    });
            });        

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/malark/general/jqdock/jquery.jqDock.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/malark/general/jqdock/stack-2.js"></script>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function() {
            //accordeon menu 
            // Store variables
            var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
            accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');     

            // Open the first tab on load
            accordion_head.eq(0).addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

            // Click function
            accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {    
                // Disable header links
                event.preventDefault(); 
                // Show and hide the tabs on click        
                if ($(this).attr('class') !== 'active'){
                    accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
                    $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
                    accordion_head.removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                    });
            });        
        </script>

        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="home.js"></script>

      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">        
            <div id="rightbox">
                <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/malark/general/navigation_user.php" ?>            
            </div>
            <div id="cheader">
                <img src="../images/logo_EB.gif" alt="logo ING EB"/>
                <h2>ING Employee Benefits</h2>                
            </div>
            <div id="csubheader">
                <i>user tips appear here</i>
                <hr class="horizontal_line" />          
            </div>
            <div id="cbody">
                <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/malark/general/stackdock.php" ?>
            </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: why are you including jQuery two times?

Comment: They are two different jQuery library versions, and both seem to be incompatible. Is it wrong to do this?

Comment: wow, jquery 1.3.2 is very outdated, do you need it?  If it is for some sort of accordion plugin (as I see you have a seperate css file), you should use [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/). `noconflict` only stops jquery from conflicting with other libraries that aren't jquery (not other versions of jquery)

Comment: Oh okay :-/ Unfortunately, the code for the vertical stackdock does not work properly with JQuery version 1.9.1 and it was written a long time ago. I really liked this menu though, it is still widely available on the internet :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is untested.

```
<script> 

     $(document).ready(function () {
        //use your old plug in

     }

</script>


<script src="jquery.1.9.1"></script>
```

//load accordion

```
<script>


       jq191 = jQuery.noConflict();

        jq191(document).ready(function() {

        }


</script>
```

... Now $ is for the old 1.3.1 jQuery and jq191 is for the second version. The only differences with your code is I don't think the first noConflict is relevant and I've used jq191 to make sure that the second block of code runs with the second version of jQuery.

It is perfectly possible to do what you want to do.

OH. Also include these two lines

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/malark/general/jqdock/jquery.jqDock.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/malark/general/jqdock/stack-2.js"></script>
```

straight after loading 1.3.2 if they are the plugin which uses that version of jQuery i.e before the code block which uses them. And I don't see the accordion loaded - load that after the second version of jQuery is loaded.

--JustinWyllie